# Applying gradient in spherical coordinates to vector in cartesian coordinates

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, differentiation, vector-fields

I am trying to calculate the gradient of a vector field $\boldsymbol{u}$.

In cartesian coordinates, I would normally do

$$\left(\nabla\boldsymbol{u}\right)_{ij}=\partial_{i}u_{j}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\partial_{x}u_{x} & \partial_{x}u_{y} & \partial_{x}u_{z}\\
\partial_{y}u_{x} & \partial_{y}u_{y} & \partial_{y}u_{z}\\
\partial_{z}u_{x} & \partial_{z}u_{y} & \partial_{z}u_{z}
\end{array}\right)$$

but I want to express the gradient in spherical coordinates, *i.e.*

$$\nabla\boldsymbol{u}=\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}\partial_{r}+\frac{\hat{\theta}}{r}\partial_{\theta}\frac{\hat{\phi}}{r\sin\theta}\partial_{\phi}\right)\boldsymbol{u}$$

However, $\boldsymbol{u}$ is defined as $$u_i = M_{ij} f_j$$, in cartesian components. $M=M(x,y,z)$ is a complicated expression, whereas $f$ is constant. So I should convert $u$ to spherical coordinates by transforming both $M$ and $f$ first, then apply the gradient $\nabla$ in spherical coordinates.
This is quite laborious and in the end not crucial to my end goal, which is to integrate $\nabla \boldsymbol{u}$ over a spherical surface.

So my question is, could I leave $\boldsymbol{u}$ in cartesian coordinates and apply the gradient in spherical coordinates to it? This would look something like

$$\left(\nabla\boldsymbol{u}\right)_{11}=\partial_{r}u_{x}$$
$$\left(\nabla\boldsymbol{u}\right)_{12}=\partial_{r}u_{y}$$
$$\left(\nabla\boldsymbol{u}\right)_{22}=r^{-1}\partial_{\theta}u_{x}$$
$$\left(\nabla\boldsymbol{u}\right)_{22}=r^{-1}\partial_{\theta}u_{y}$$
$$\text{etc.}...$$

Would this present problems when integrating over a sphere, *e.g.*

$$\iint_{S}\nabla\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\boldsymbol{dS}\ \ ?$$

How should $\boldsymbol{dS}$ be rewritten in order for this hybrid formulation to make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarification, write $\vec{u} = u_x \hat{x} + u_y \hat{y} + u_z\hat{z}$ in components, and $d\vec{S} = \hat{r} R^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$
$$
  \vec{I} \equiv  \oint \oint \vec{\nabla} \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{S}
$$
\begin{align}
   I_\alpha = & \oint \oint \vec{\nabla} u_\alpha(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{S}\\
=&  R^2 \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \frac{\partial u_\alpha(\vec{r})}{\partial r}\\
=& R^2 \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \left\{\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \frac{\partial u_\alpha(\vec{r})}{\partial x}  +\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \frac{\partial u_\alpha(\vec{r})}{\partial y}  + \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \frac{\partial u_\alpha(\vec{r})}{\partial z} \right\}\\
=& R^2 \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \left\{\sin\theta\cos\phi \frac{\partial u_\alpha(\vec{r})}{\partial x}  +\sin\theta\sin\phi \frac{\partial u_\alpha(\vec{r})}{\partial y}  + \cos\theta \frac{\partial u_\alpha(\vec{r})}{\partial z} \right\}
\end{align}

Where we use
\begin{align}
  x = & r \sin\theta\cos\phi;\\
  y = & r \sin\theta\sin\phi;\\
  z = & r \cos\theta.
\end{align}

Comment: I see.. However, I can't see how this formalism would apply to, say, the integral of $\left(\nabla\boldsymbol{u}\right)^{T}$, or $\mathbb{I}$ (identity matrix)

Comment: Also, why is there a sum over $\alpha$ in your integrals? Did you mean $I_\alpha = ...$ instead?

Comment: "why is there a sum over α "? I worte $\vec{u} = \sum_a \hat{a} u_a$. The "$\cdot$" is operate between $\vec{\nabla}$ and $d\vec{S}$.

Comment: If you cannot tell how to decompose, just write all in indices form.

Comment: So it should not be present in the first line, right? Also, I understood that the cdot operator gives only the $\hat{r}$ component, so no need for the others?

Comment: Also, in the third and forth line the sums are explicit, so no need for the sum symbol

Comment: (1) It has to be sum over $\alpha$, or you may write $I_\alpha = $ without summation and unit vector. (2) Yes. inner product leave on the r-component.

Comment: Let me edit to a form your feel confortable.